# Kubernetes, partitioning around clusters and namespaces

Tags: cluster, kubernetes, namespaces

Let's say we have 2 subsystems: A & B. 
And we have 2 env: QA & Prod.

What would be a better way to organize it around cluster & namespace?. Is it:

1. One cluster for subsystem A, another cluster for subsystem B. And within each cluster, we partition with namespace: a namespace for QA, another namespace for Prod.

or...

2. One cluster for env QA, another cluster for env Prod. And... within each cluster: a namespace for subsystem A, and another namespace for subsystem B.

What are the pro & cons of each alternative?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From general description both ideas look more or less equal, however, it's pretty tricky to compare your options without understanding of your infrastructure, environments, isolation requirements, etc.

Could you provide some details about your case?